# rsync with AppleScript, copy from other volume

Tags: applescript, rsync, automator

I'm trying to build a automatic backup solution. My AppleScript commands are pretty simple. All I want to do is copy all the files in one folder to a different folder.

Currently I'm using this:

```
rsync --update -raz --progress Documents/test "Volumes/RFM_Projects_2"
```

This works when I have my files located in a folder called test in the Documents folder. Problem is that I have a different folder structure now where I have all the files I want to copy on a second internal harddrive.

I thought it would be easy to just change `"Documents/test"` to something like `"Volumes/WORK/test"`, but this does not work at all.

Any ideas about how I can change the source location to a secondary harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

All slash-delimited style paths, like the ones used in your rsync command, must start with a slash (/). That slash stands for the startup volume drive. I do not see that first slash in any of your paths so I'm surprised any of your code ever worked. Here's an applescript which will show you the path. Run this, select any folder you want, and copy/paste the result into your code. Note that if there are any spaces in any of your paths then you should put your paths in quotes in your rsync command.

```
choose folder
return POSIX path of result
```

Also note if you want the path to a file instead of a folder then change the word folder to file in the applescript. Good luck.